How to add module inside an Android module?
Having the following structure.
-root

app
module1
module2

libs

submodule





How to add module inside an Android module? This means that the module2 should still detect the submodule even without having specifying it in settings.gradle.
Currently implementation(project(":libs:submodule")) in build.gradle.kts of module2 is not working. It will work however if we do this
-root

app
module1
module2 (still depends on submodule but located in root/project level)
submodule

This is when we specified the submodule in settings.gradle
rootProject.name = "Sample App"
include(":app")
include(":module1")
include (":module2") // Has dependency to submodule
include (":submodule")

But what we want is for module2 to already include submodule so we don't need to specify in the project the submodule.

dependencies management is different from settings.gradle module management. so now your settings.gradle file may look like
include ':app'
include ':module1'
include ':module2'
include ':module2:libs'
include ':module2:libs:submodule'

i don't have the complete specifics on how you plan to use each module so i listed the maximum.

None of the modules are dependent on any other unless they are mentioned in build.gradle file of another module.
For creating module inside a module you can just move it to another module and update its directory graph in settings.gradle file appropriately.
So, I created two new modules test1, test2. I now created a new directory called tests. after this I moved my two modules from project directory to tests directory. I edit my settings.gradle file which had
include ':app'
include ':translations'
include ':test1'
include ':test2'

and updated it to following:
include ':app'
include ':translations'
include 'tests:test1'
include 'tests:test2'

then I created another directory inside tests directory called subtest and moved the test2 module there. then i updated my settings.gradle file to
include ':app'
include ':translations'
include 'tests:test1'
include 'tests:subtest:test2'

And I did it in the project configuration like in the following image:

and now it looks something like:


The only thing you did here is creating a folder and moved both test1 and test2 module. What I am trying to do is something like test2 inside libs folder of test1 so test1 when consumed via implementation(project(":test1")) should work already and no longer need any additional setup on settings.gradle

then use api instead of implementation
